# HTML5 valid Google+ Button - Bad value publisher for attribute rel

Tags: html, google-plus-one

I recently migrated my website from xhtml transitional to html5. Specifically so that I could make use of valid block level anchor tags. `<a><div /></a>`.

When running validation I encountered the following error:

> Bad value publisher for attribute rel on element link: Keyword
>   publisher is not registered.

But according to this page, that is exactly what I am supposed to do.

https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/badge/#connect

My code:

```
<link href="https://plus.google.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" rel="publisher" />

<a href="https://plus.google.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx?prsrc=3" style="text-decoration:none;">
  <img src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/images/icons/gplus-16.png" alt="" style="border:0;width:16px;height:16px;"/>
</a>
```

I can't figure out how to implement this in an html5 compliant way. Can anyone help?

Comment: You'd be better off going to StackOverflow, as this is a programming question instead of a Webmaster question.

Comment: @Christopher - I actually chose WM on purpose as it seems like something webmasters would be familiar with. If I am wrong I would appreciate a flag for transfer though. I have too little rep to do it here.

Comment: I don't think there's any tidy solution for this. [publisher has been dropped](http://microformats.org/wiki/existing-rel-values#dropped) and the google code still requires it. I'd ignore the error from (validator.nu?) and keep an eye on the google docs to see if they update the code to use a valid `rel` value (or switch to something else like `data-publisher`).

Answer (score 3):

**1st**) Within `<head>`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <!--head code-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>
</head>
```

**2nd**) Anywhere within `<body>`:

```
<body>
    <!--body code-->
    <div class="g-plusone" data-size="small" data-annotation="none" data-href="https://plus.google.com/u/1/+StackExchange/"></div>
</body>
```

This code is valid AND "FRIEND'S" with http://validator.w3.org/

You can change `https://plus.google.com/u/1/+StackExchange/` for any google+ url you desire (`https://plus.google.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/`)

[**Documentation**](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/#plusonetag)

Answer (score 0):

Google sends help: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2539557&topic=2371375&ctx=topic.

You need to add `?rel=author` to your `<a>`s href value and delete that non-conformant `<link>` tag:

```
<a href="https://plus.google.com/12345?rel=author">
  <img src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/images/icons/gplus-16.png"/>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you must add two links inside head tag and body tag as follows:

```
<head>
  <link href='https://plus.google.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' itemprop='publisher'/>
</head>
```

After that, use the the google+ format in the body. It should be below body tag:

```
<body>
<a href="https://plus.google.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" rel="publisher" />
.....
.....
.....
</body>
```

here's the screenshot.
Oops! sorry, I need 10 reputation to load Image in this page ... LOL
From the two formats, we will be validated by Structured Data of Google Webmaster and validator.w3.org.
As you know that in microdata schema uses publisher as one of the itemprop, therefore, in body tag or in html tag should be like this:

```
<body itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Blog">
```

*) that's it when your site type is a BLOG.

(Love this forum) tina-andrew-blog
    NB: I found this: https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/webmasters/lciIK8HdJXE/kcv8EipRzzcJ
But, I do with the code above, It works well :(